# Auto play/pause HTML5 video with jQuery and in-view.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, inview

I use the jquery inview plugin top automatically play videos when in view. I have try many solutions from stackoverflow but it does not seem to work ([solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174828/facebook-like-video-autoplay-and-pause), [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879280/html5-video-with-jquery-and-inview-how-to-point-to-the-right-video-element))

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.inview/0.2/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.video-autoplay').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
      $('video').trigger('play');
    } else {
      $('video').trigger('pause');
    }
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div class="navbar gallery-sub-header" style="z-index:9;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="pull-left desc-follow">
          <div class="single-item">
            <video class=".video-autoplay" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted playsinline onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" poster="">
            <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/images/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.webm' }}" type="video/webm">
            <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/video-gif/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          </div>
          <div class="single-item">
            <video class=".video-autoplay" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted playsinline onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" poster="">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/images/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.webm' }}" type="video/webm">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/video-gif/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="single-item">
            <video class=".video-autoplay" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted playsinline onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" poster="">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/images/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.webm' }}" type="video/webm">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/video-gif/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
           </video>
          </div>
          <div class="single-item">
            <video class=".video-autoplay" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted playsinline onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" poster="">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/images/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.webm' }}" type="video/webm">
              <source src="{{ Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . '/video-gif/' . substr($item->pic_url, 0, strripos($item->pic_url, '.')) . '.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It might also be worth running your HTML through a validator too. Your closing script tags on line 1 and line 9 need attention. This may be contributing to the problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly, due to the location of your jQuery logic, you need to wrap it in a document.ready handler. Currently you're executing the JS before the DOM has been loaded, and no elements exist.

Secondly, when the event fires you select all `video` elements. From the context of the event handler I would assume you instead want to start the video which is now visible/invisible, so using `$(this)` would seem more applicable. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.video-autoplay').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
    $(this).trigger(isInView ? 'play' : 'pause');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory. I replaced your script with mine, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Oops! It actually works. Just the video still play even when it is not fully in view.